# Array being treated as object, unable to NgFor

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to call a new endpoint to display data, I realise that in the previous set of data that works, it consoles with an extra '[]' pair of brackets around the data, I think this is where the problem is, whereas the new endpoint doesnt produce it with the way im using the data!

it's the NgFor thats failing: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'Industry's Next Frontier'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

the old endpoint uses an interface to store the data and just accesses that, while the new endpoint returns the json and trys to store it in an array to then be used by the ngfor.

I'll show first the html code:

```
    <div *ngFor="let sessions of getSortedSessionList()">
  <tl-title
    *ngIf="sessions[0]"
    [title]="getSessionDay(sessions[0].startDatetime)"
    [explore]="true">
  </tl-title>
  <div *ngFor="let session of sessions">
    <tl-session-card
      [title]="session.name"
      [startTime]="getSessionTime(session.startDatetime, true)"
      [endTime]="getSessionTime(session.endDatetime, false)"
      [location]="getLocation(session.location)"
      [path]="sessionPath(session.id, session.name)">
    </tl-session-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think the reason why the new endpoint may not be working is because it's somehow hasnt got rid of the object brackets somewhere:

the endpoint (engagementService):

```
 public sessionData: any[];

 this.sessions(n.id)
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.sessionData = data;
      }
```

Then when I use the data in my other file:

```
  sessionList: any[];

          this.sessionList = this.engagementService.sessionData;

  getSortedSessionList() {


console.log('consoling within getSortedSessionList' + JSON.stringify(this.sessionList))
return this.sessionList;
```

}

the data returns like this:

```
[{
    "id": "a0Wb0000006RoHwEAK",
    "endDatetime": "2017-01-19T18:00:00.000+0000",
    "location": "Davos-Klosters, Congress Centre, Sanada",
    "name": "Industry's Next Frontier",
    "photoURL": "https://fwsqa.weforum.org/images/sessions/a0Wb0000006RoHwEAK/standard"
}]
```

Yet the original endpoint which works, returns the data like this: 
(with the additional '[]' which is making the difference I think!)

```
[
[{
        "id": "a0Wb0000006RqNlEAK",
        "endDatetime": "2017-01-20T09:15:00.000+0000",
        "location": "Davos-Klosters, Congress Centre, xChange",
        "name": "Fertile Ground for Sustainable Growth",
        "photoURL": "https://fwsqa.weforum.org/images/sessions/a0Wb0000006RqNlEAK/standard",
        "roles": null,
        "startDatetime": "2017-01-20T08:00:00.000+0000",
        "thumbnailURL" }] 
]
```

the data is retrieved in a similar way yet its called from an endpoint 
and then accessed via an interface:

```
export interface IEngagementSideContentData {

sessionList?: any;
}

  @Input() data: IEngagementSideContentData;

  getSortedSessionList() {
if (!this.sessionList) {
  this.sessionList = this.data.sessionList.sort(this.dateSort);
}
```

somehow this old endpoint and the use of the interface is meaning there is an extra bracket and the ngfor works, any advice would be great thanks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have this:

```
<div *ngFor="let sessions of getSortedSessionList()">
```

Then inside that you have this:

```
<div *ngFor="let session of sessions">
```

What is getSortedSessionList() returning? An array of an array of sessions? (That would be where the extra `[]` comes from?)

Which of these ngFor statements is generating the error?

The HTML is saying to get an array of an array of sessions using getSortedSessionsList()

Then for each session array in that array, to process each session.

I would think that you would use this

```
<div *ngFor="let session of getSortedSessionList()">
```

Notice the singular `session` here. Not both `*ngFor` statements.

But I'm not sure I understand your requirements.

Comment: Thanks deborah, pointing out that the sessions of getSortedSessionList() showed me my error, the old endpoint was using an Object.keys method on the data which resulted in the extra [] being used. The logic was built around expecting this format so when I introduced the new endpoint without then manipulating the data in the same way, it couldnt then be used by this ngFor, so I applied the old logic on the new data :D

Answer (score 0):

You should loop `sessionData` not `sessions`

```
<div *ngFor="let session of sessionData">
```

Comment: Why is it that?

Comment: Because session is an observable. U need to resolve the observable to access the data

Comment: The original endpoint doesnt call on the sessions observable it calls on something else. When I changed it to sessionData it just showed some dates with the rest of the data empty